# Not able to stop a service?

Tags: android

Here is my code for starting a service:

I am starting my service in onCreate() of my Activity.

```
  Intent svc=new Intent(BeapSoundActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
               pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(BeapSoundActivity.this, 0, svc, 0);

               AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
               calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
               alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, pendingIntent);
```

I cant able to stop a service by calling

stopService();

Here is my Service class:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service{

//   private static final String TAG = null;
//   MediaPlayer player;
     MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
     String  strResponse;
     int i=0;

     static {

//         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build());
       }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        Log.e("Oncreate","oncreate");


    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//        player.start();
        Log.e("Onstartcommand","onstartcommand");

            pendingCount();

        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
//      super.onStart(intent,startId);



        Log.e("Onstart","onstart");
//      pendingCount();
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

     this.stopSelf();


    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

         super.onDestroy();

            this.stopSelf();

//        player.stop();
//        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }


}

    public void pendingCount(){

            my operations during the service

                 }


    }


}
```

I have also tried with stopSelf() in my onDestroy(),but it also didnt worked for me.

Please suggest how can I solve this issue?

Comment: y u need static block.

Comment: its just some times I cant able to use my webservices,I dont think this is the problem, stopService() calls onDestroy method ,where I keep this.stopSelf(),but it didnt worked

Comment: are u doing any counter operation using anonymous class or any other mean inside pendingCount()... If yes then I think i know the solution

Comment: yes I am calling the webservice,and just using that response

Comment: you need to stop `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 0):

you've to call `stopService()` from another activity. Or you can call `stopSelf()` in the service (not in `onDestroy()`) when the required work finishes.

Comment: yes I called stopService() from the Activity where I have started the service, when the user clicks on a back button.

Comment: try removing the static block, I guess it's keeping the service alive. also try returning `2`from `onStartCommand` & remove the `onStart()` method. Also `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code it may help you.

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackgroundService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can see that your stopservice() is  working fine to stop the service but anonymous class or what ever you are using inside pendingCount() is still working even though service is destroyed..
So do some thing like this

**Rise a flag** in ondestroy() and check this  inside **pendingCount() looping part** and if this flag is high destroy this task also. For more accurate answer add complete pendingCount() 
code